# Expression must have arithmetic type error with float pointer

Tags: c

I have simple C code below. When I compile this, I get the warning “expression must have arithmetic type” in the line that I want to print the `bPtr` and `*bPtr` with `printf` routine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a=5, *aPtr;
float b = 3.2, *bPtr;
double c = 3.412, *cPtr;
char d = 'a', *dPtr;

int numbers[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int *arrayPtr;

aPtr = &a;
bPtr = &b;
cPtr = &c;
dPtr = &d;
arrayPtr = &numbers[1];

printf("%u adresindeki int in degeri %d dir\n", aPtr, *aPtr);
printf("%u adresindeki float in degeri %f dir\n", bPtr *bPtr);
printf("%u adresindeki double in degeri %lf dir\n", cPtr, *cPtr);
printf("%u adresindeki char in degeri %c dir\n", dPtr, *dPtr);
printf("%u adresindeki sayilarin elemaninin degeri %d dir\n", arrayPtr, 
*arrayPtr);


system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not format addresses with `%u`. Use `%p` and convert the pointer to `void *` when passing it to `printf`.

Comment: oh that was a terrible mistake. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bptr` `printf` is missing a comma. The resulting source code, `b *bptr`, attempts to multiply a `float` by a pointer, which causes the error message.

Comment: OMG. That was a terrible mistake. Thanks a lot.